# Saving GDI+ Metafile as BMP cropped when screen scaling not 100%

Tags: c++, gdi+

When saving a bitmap file from a GDI+ metafile object, the output is affected by the current display scale of the monitor.

For example, the following code sample generates these images:

[image: Full image when screen at 100% scaling] with screen at 100% scaling (81x81 pixel bitmap generated).

[image: Cropped image when screen at 125% scaling] with screen at 125% scaling (52x52 pixel bitmap generated).

```
#include <Windows.h>

// GDI+ libraries
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")

void main()
{
    // Startup GDI+
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, nullptr);

    {
        // Create a metafile
        const auto dc = GetDC(nullptr);
        const auto cdc = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
        Gdiplus::Metafile metafile{ L"test.emf", cdc };
        auto graphics = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(&metafile);

        // Draw some things
        Gdiplus::SolidBrush yellowBrush{ Gdiplus::Color::Yellow };
        graphics->FillRectangle(&yellowBrush, 0, 0, 70, 70);
        Gdiplus::SolidBrush redBrush(Gdiplus::Color::Red);
        graphics->FillRectangle(&redBrush, 10, 10, 50, 50);
        delete graphics; // Must be deleted before saving (is this the correct way?)

        // Save as BMP (MIME type: image/bmp)
        CLSID bmpEncoderId{1434252288, 6660, 4563, {154, 115, 0, 0, 248, 30, 243, 46}};
        auto status = metafile.Save(L"test.bmp", &bmpEncoderId);

        // Cleanup
        DeleteDC(cdc);
        ReleaseDC(nullptr, dc);
    }

    // Shutdown GDI+
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

I've tried adding the following in several places (as suggested in other SO answers) but this doesn't seem to change the behviour.

```
// Set scaling
Gdiplus::MetafileHeader mfh{};
metafile.GetMetafileHeader(&mfh);
graphics->ScaleTransform(mfh.GetDpiX() / graphics->GetDpiX(),
                         mfh.GetDpiY() / graphics->GetDpiY());
```

Is it possible to export the full bitmap image independent of what scaling is set on the monitor?

**SOLUTION**: This was caused by not compiling as DPI-aware.

Comment: Is your application DPI-aware?

Comment: Yes. That's fixed it. The main application was DPI aware but it was calling a separate program that wasn't. Thanks.

Comment: Now I just need to deal with the text changing size when DPI awareness is enabled :)